# Resolving nodejs modules from other than node_modules location, is it possible?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

For example, when I need a module located inside `node_modules` I can write `const module = require('module')` or `import module from 'module'`. If the module located in another location I need to write `const module = require('../location/module')`, etc...

This behavior not always desired, for example, If I have examples that I want a user will be able to copy/paste and run, and also to run this example from the project folder itself.

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why I get downvoted, but I ended up to write the following wrapper which does the job:

```js
const customRequire = function (moduleName, path) {
  let module
  try {
    module = require(moduleName)
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      module = require(`${path}/${moduleName}`)
    } catch (e1) {
      throw Error(`module ${moduleName} on path ${path} wasn't found`)
    }
  }
  return module
}
```

Now if you copy/paste this code it will work. And if you will run it within the project where required modules defined and not located in `node_modules` it will work too.

The solution above work for the CommonJS module system, for ES6 you need to use the function [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), to [dynamically import modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports)

```js
import('/modules/my-module.js')
  .then((module) => {
    // Do something with the module.
  });
```